# two separate blogs on one wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, posts

I did find one topic that sort of touched base on this but if there is a better link please advise.

I have a self hosted Wordpress website set up typically for a static home page and a separate page that shows recent posts called "Reviews". I need to write posts under a category "Recent News" that would be excluded from the recent post and shown on their own page, a second blog page.

The Codex tells me to add this to the index.php to exclude the category "recent-news":

```
<?php
if (is_home()) {
query_posts("cat=-3");
}
?>
```

with 3 being "recent-news". This does nothing no matter where I place it on the page. It still shows up with the recent posts. I'm guessing I'm in the wrong section for excluding categories in the Codex.

How do I exclude a category from recent posts, add a new page called "Recent News" and have it only show posts from the 'recent-news" category.

or have I climbed down a rabbit hole...

Comment: `cat=-3` is a parameter to your Wordpress query, you need to add it as a parameter to your loop / wp_query call. Just pasting it to page will not work. As always, start with reading the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category

Comment: That is very helpful, and I ended up with that snippet via a wordpress.org forum topic. That is where they said to just place it in the index.php. Thank you for the link @PetrCibulka, is what I'm trying to achieve though, possible? Two seperate post pages?

Comment: Of course. Follow the advice of Talsibony below. However it seems that your knowledge of Wordpress is somehow limited, so I would recommend for you to read some beginner articles/tutorials first ...

Comment: @PetrCibulka you are correct, and that is why I am here to learn, but will also take your advice on reading many resources, Thank you.

Comment: There are many resources online. Official WP beginner roundup is here (pointed to the chapter which applies to your current situation): http://codex.wordpress.org/New_To_WordPress_-_Where_to_Start#Appearance_and_Themes Read more about Wordpress loop and template files / template hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this: edit your index.php page or create a custom template and then create a page (say "Front Page" ) and assign this template to it. In this template, copy your index.php code or if you feel confident simply create your template and include this code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $my_query=new WP_Query( 'cat=-3'); while 
   ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;  ?>
    <div class="post">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

About your second question, simply go to Appearance --> Menu and there you'll see you can add pages but also **categories**. Simply select the category **"Recent News"** as a menu element and voilá, now you'll have a page displaying only posts from that category

Comment: About the menu @fabio, I had guessed that was the solution but needed verification. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommand messing with index.php
I think you should create a page template that will query posts from "Recent News" category.
Then in wordpress create a page and choose the page template you created.
In order to set it as the home page you will have to set it via wordpress configurations.
[Wordpress page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

[query posts by category](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-database-query-selecting-posts-of-one-category)

[Set static homepage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Comment: thank you. It will be a separate sub-menu item but the same rule applies, right?

Comment: Ok so you need the posts from category X will be in some menu? if this is the case you will have to run on the loop and get the post link from the post http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories